# Plugin Architecture not storing plugin classes

Tags: python-3.x, list, oop, import, plugins

**Background:**

I'm creating a controller to control a WS2811 LED strip with Adafruit's Neopixel python library and my raspberry pi 4 b. To make it easy to add different themes, led patterns, and logic, I decided to build the software on a plugin architecture.

**Resources:**
My github repo: https://github.com/lamaprogramer/PiWS2811Controller

Resources I was following on python plugin architecture:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/07/fundamental-concepts-of-plugin-infrastructures

https://gist.github.com/dorneanu/cce1cd6711969d581873a88e0257e312

**Problem:**

The problem is that it wont store the classes of the plugins it finds.

```py
# tools/pattern/ColorPatterns.py

from importlib import util
import os


class PatternRegistry(type):
    patterns = []
    
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if name != "ColorPattern":
            cls.patterns.append(cls)
            print(cls.patterns)
            

class ColorPattern(object, metaclass=PatternRegistry):   
    def pattern(self, pixels, pixelCount, theme): raise NotImplementedError
    
    

def loadPatterns(path):
    for fname in os.listdir(path):
        if not fname.startswith("__") and not fname.startswith(".") and fname.endswith(".py"):
            load(os.path.join(path, fname))
    return PatternRegistry.patterns

def load(path):
    name = os.path.split(path)[-1]
    #print("loaded: " + name)
    spec = util.spec_from_file_location(name, path)
    module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

This is the file that has utilities for loading the plugins, in a separate class, I have a class that calls the `loadPatterns()` function:

```py
# tools/pattern/PatternManager.py

import tools.pattern.ColorPatterns as plugin

class PatternManager:

    def __init__(self, path):
        print("returned plugins: " + str(plugin.loadPatterns(path)))
```

Which should load any modules it finds and, in theory, save the plugin class to the `patterns` variable in `PatternRegistry`.

At first it seems to load the plugins, because if I print `patterns` in the constructor of the `PatternRegistry`, it will print `patterns` when a plugin is found and it will contain every plugin loaded at the time, this is what my output is after the program is run:

```
loaded plugins: [<class 'FadePattern.py.FadePattern'>]
loaded plugins: [<class 'FadePattern.py.FadePattern'>, <class 'ShiftPattern.py.ShiftPattern'>]
returned plugins: []
```

But if I access the `patterns` variable from anywhere outside the class, it returns an empty list,

I know it finds the plugin, however it seems to either not add the plugin class to a list, or it gets rid of the value at some point.

Looking online, I thought it could be a problem with my imports, so I tried importing a few different ways, however none seemed to work. I also tried making the `patterns` variable global, and moving it to a different class, neither worked. moving files around didn't seem to have much of an effect